# How to build a list and bring the data from JSON?

Tags: android, json

I'm developing in Android Studio, for Android devices, and I'm doing an app that needs to build a list and bring the data to it from JSON thru standard HTML calls.

Can someone please give a code example for a list that does that, or even a sample project with a list that shows data from JSON that you download?

I'm talking about JSON like this:

http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo

```
{
  "geonames": [
    {
      "lng": -99.12766456604,
      "geonameId": 3530597,
      "countrycode": "MX",
      "name": "Mexiko-Stadt",
      "fclName": "city, village,...",
      "toponymName": "Mexico City",
      "fcodeName": "capital of a political entity",
      "wikipedia": "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexico_City",
      "lat": 19.428472427036,
      "fcl": "P",
      "population": 12294193,
      "fcode": "PPLC"
    },
    {
      "lng": 116.397228240967,
      "geonameId": 1816670,
      "countrycode": "CN",
      "name": "Peking",
      "fclName": "city, village,...",
      "toponymName": "Beijing",
      "fcodeName": "capital of a political entity",
      "wikipedia": "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beijing",
      "lat": 39.9074977414405,
      "fcl": "P",
      "population": 11716620,
      "fcode": "PPLC"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why up vote for this questions ??

Comment: try using gson library

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make a simple list view and than parse the json in list adapter.

Please look to given example [android-json-parsing-tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/).

Hope this will help you